# Meteor.js : add a date picker to a page

Tags: meteor

I'm trying hard to get a date picker on my meteor application. I tested lot of packages found by googling, but none seems to work, or, probably, I'm doing it wrong. Can someone tell me clearly how to add a date picker?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I would use the **bootstrap 3** package and the **bootstrap 3 date time picker** package:

```
$ meteor add twbs:bootstrap
$ meteor add tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker
```

Then, simply add the form in your **HTML** file:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <form>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="myInput">Input name</label>
          <div class="input-group datetimepicker">
             <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
             <input name="idInput" id="idInput" class="set-due-date form-control" type="text"/>
           </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

And in your corresponding **JavaScript** file, you have to initialize your date time picker:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
};
```

And if you have different date input in your page (for example):

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){
     $('.datetimepicker').each(function(){
           $(this).datetimepicker(); 
     });
}
```

Finally, I invite you to read the [Documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) if you need more options (like date format etc).

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have two questions. First, I don't find any documentation about how to get the picked datetime on the JS side. The only thing I succeeded was to retrieve the raw text in the text input. Is this the right method? How do I get a Date (or Datetime) object than I can insert in the database?

My second problem is that the input don't take the full height, see:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60498064/Capture.PNG

How can I get the good height for the input?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. For your second problem, if you write the exact same code that I wrote to you, you shouldn't get your issue, except if you overwrited some CSS. Then it shouldn't be hard to fix it :) Then, to get your date value in your Template submit event just do something like : `var date = $(e.target).find('[name=dateInput]').val()` (or idInput in my previous example). Hope it'll help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use [the one from eonasdon](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) (Bootstrap required) and you get get it prepackaged by doing this:

```
meteor add hujhax:bootstrap3-datetimepicker
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

What bootstrap package do you use (bootstrap, nemo64:bootstrap, mrt:bootstrap-3, twbs:bootstrap, ...) ?

Comment: Personally I use nemo64 since it uses the origianl less files and lets me change the variables.

Comment: It's perfectly working! How you get the chosen date in JS code?

Answer (score 1):

I have these packages added

twbs:bootstrap
jquery
rajit:bootstrap3-datepicker

and used this in the template

```
<div class="box-body no-padding">
    <!--The calendar -->
    <div id="calendar" style="width: 100%"></div>
</div><!-- /.box-body -->
```

and added helper below

```
Template.myCalendar.rendered = function() {
    $('#calendar').datepicker();
}
```